# Using Geoserver URL as variable in Leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I'm trying to use a string variable within a image tag that then adds a symbol to the layer control in Leaflet.

I'm having trouble with the whole use of single/double quotes and concatenating the variable. Does anyone have experience of this issue.

```
var legendUrl = 'https://maps.dartmoor.gov.uk/geoserver/wms?REQUEST=GetLegendGraphic&VERSION=1.0.0&FORMAT=image/png&WIDTH=20&HEIGHT=20&LAYER='

overlays = {
"<img align=top src = ""'"+legendUrl+"'""hta:sssi'/> SSSI":'hta:sssi'
"<img align=top src = 'http://maps.dartmoor.gov.uk/geoserver/wms?REQUEST=GetLegendGraphic&VERSION=1.0.0&FORMAT=image/png&WIDTH=20&HEIGHT=20&LAYER=general:tpo_area'/> TPO Areas":'general:tpo_area'

};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
overlays = {
  "<img align=top src = '" + legendUrl + "hta:sssi'/> SSSI" : 'hta:sssi',
  "<img align=top src = 'http://maps.dartmoor.gov.uk/geoserver/wms?REQUEST=GetLegendGraphic&VERSION=1.0.0&FORMAT=image/png&WIDTH=20&HEIGHT=20&LAYER=general:tpo_area'/> TPO Areas" : 'general:tpo_area'
};
```

If you cannot use computed property names in the object initializer, then an alternate solution would be something like:

```
var overlays = {};
overlays["<img align=top src = '" + legendUrl + "hta:sssi'/> SSSI"] = 'hta:sssi';
```

Comment: Thanks but that still doesn't work for me. I think I'm doing something fundamentally wrong here. 
Here's the page https://maps.dartmoor.gov.uk/wms_info_possible.html

Comment: Missing comma. Be sure to read the documentation about the [JS `Object` initializer format](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer).

Comment: I had added the comma myself so it wasn't that. I'm a bit lost as to why this won't work but I'll do some reading and get back to you. Thanks.

Comment: Found out about [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) using the docs link. Thanks for your help

Comment: Unfortunately computed property names are not yet compatible with all browsers and I'm not in the position to use a transpiler like babel. I don't understand why you answer does not work though. The error I'm getting is:
`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token +`

Comment: See updated answer

Answer (score 1):

Turns out you need to wrap the key in expression in brackets [] as its trying to use a computed property name.

```
  ["<img align='top' src ='" + legendUrl + "hta:sssi'/> SSSI"] : 'hta:sssi'
```